# Creating a SCOPE for an association with more than 3 models - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could one kindly advise me where i am going wrong with my SQL query

> i want to display a company's list of forms that only have an accepted
>   status `@company.forms.created_this_month.forms_accepted.count` but i
>   get the below error. i am unsure where i am going wrong - any advise
>   and help will be much appreciated

```
error in terminal:
2.1.2 :043 >   company.forms.created_this_month.forms_accepted
  Form Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "forms".* FROM "forms" INNER JOIN "adverts" ON "forms"."advert_id" = "adverts"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "adverts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."company_id" = ? AND ("forms"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-03-31 22:59:59.999999') AND (status = 'Accepted')  [["company_id", 1]]
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: status: SELECT "forms".* FROM "forms" INNER JOIN "adverts" ON "forms"."advert_id" = "adverts"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "adverts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."company_id" = ? AND ("forms"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-03-31 22:59:59.999999') AND (status = 'Accepted')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: status: SELECT "forms".* FROM "forms" INNER JOIN "adverts" ON "forms"."advert_id" = "adverts"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "adverts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."company_id" = ? AND ("forms"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-03-31 22:59:59.999999') AND (status = 'Accepted')


models
company.rb
has_many users
has_many :forms, through: :users

user.rb
belongs_to company
has_many adverts

advert.rb
belongs_to user
has_many forms

form.rb
belongs_to advert
scope :forms_accepted, -> {where(['status = ?', 'Accepted'])}
scope :created_this_month, -> { where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }


schema
  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "companyname"
    t.string   "tel"
    t.string   "email"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.integer  "company_id"
  end

  create_table "adverts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "forms", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "currentJob"
    t.string   "currentEmployer"
    t.integer  "advert_id"
    t.string   "status"
  end
```

Comment: Change the month to:
 { where(self.class.table_name.created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }

And tell me what happens. Apparently, you are joining a bunch of tables and all of them have a field created_at. This confuses the SQL adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
scope :forms_accepted, -> {where(['status = ?', 'Accepted'])}
```

use

```
scope :forms_accepted, -> {where(status: 'Accepted'])}
```

just as you used in the second scope.

Comment: @ Mihails Butorins there was a minor syntax error in your answer but it worked when the syntax error was corrected - thank you `scope :forms_accepted, -> {where(status: 'Accepted')}` - thank you soo much

Comment: can you explain to me the difference between my scope `scope :forms_accepted, -> {where(['status = ?', 'Accepted'])}` and yours `scope :forms_accepted, -> {where(status: 'Accepted')}` is it just a rails format issue?

Comment: @ARTLoe you can see the difference if you will check the last part of the result SQL. `AND ("forms"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-03-31 22:59:59.999999') AND (status = 'Accepted')`
If `where` method specified as before, then it builds SQL without scoping on specific table what as result raise error what you have got in case if in the same query uses JOINs, because `status` column can be in different tables and database cannot determine which `status` column use. Actually `where(['forms.status = ?', 'Accepted])` will work, too. But it's not a good practice.